# Is this a mistake?

Tags: grammar

[Source](http://www.cnbc.com/id/101229716)The rules would also effect political activity by conservative and liberal grass-roots organizations, including Tea Party groups whose complaints of aggressive treatment and harassment by I.R.S. employees led to the resignation of several high-ranking agency officials **last spring.**

The IRS came to light in 2013. So it is still 2013. 
So shouldn't this be "this spring?"

Why is "last " used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found the boundaries of "this" vs. "last" when talking about time to be somewhat vague, but I think the general rule when there's some question is to refer to the one that is closer in time, whether in the past or future, as "this." Therefore if this article is current, spring 2013 was about eight months ago, whereas spring 2014 is considerably closer. If I were talking about the two, I would say spring 2013 was "last spring" and the coming spring 2014 is "this spring." They could have clarified by saying something like "this past spring," but "last spring" certainly isn't wrong in this instance.

It may also have something to do with our associations of when the cycle of seasons starts and ends, as it isn't nearly as clear cut as the calendar year. Some might say "last spring" but "this summer" when referring to both spring and summer of 2013, so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that THIS Spring is coming up (or just finished in Australia..) and LAST Spring was in 2012, even though this one has only just finished.

Also, "effect" is the noun. "Affect" is the verb.  The rules would also affect....  I think of it as the action comes first (The movie Affected me) and the result follows (It had an EFFECT on me).  "A" comes before "E" in the alphabet.

Comment: If this spring is coming up (i.e. Feb 2014) and last spring was 2012, what happened to 2013? :)

Comment: Actually I believe the use of "effect" here is correct. The verbal form of "effect" means "to cause" as in "to effect change." The sense in the example, "effect political activity" means "to cause/motivate political activity."

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i think.... last spring is used when the spring mentioned is over. 
When the spring is not over yet, this spring would be more proper.